# Use index + Match to get value given certain criteria

Tags: excel

I have a table (Table1) consisting of student names and their average scores for different subjects. I want to get the name of the student with the maximum score for a particular subject.

I was able to get the maximum score for that subject using `MAX(IF(Table1[Subject]=F5,Table1[Average Score]))`. The problem is that when I tried to get name of the student using index `=INDEX(Table1, MATCH(MAX(IF(Table1[Subject]=F5,Table1[Average Score])), Table1[Average Score], 0), 1)` I got the name of another student having the same score but for a different subject.

How do I restrict the result so that I get the student name that corresponds to that subject?

[image]

In the snapshot above, I intend to get Maxim Sunny (in cell F7) for Mathematics (cell F5) but I got Timothy Jovelyn instead.

Comment: Which version of excel do you use? If `Office365` then it is very easier to find.

Comment: I use Excel 2019 that all of a sudden started behaving like an old version. It has lost certain functions such as ifs, concat, textjoin, maxif, minif, maxifs, etc. I just don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following array formula:

```
=INDEX(Table1, MATCH(MAX(Table1[Score]*(Table1[Subject]=F5)),(Table1[Score])*(Table1[Subject]=F5), 0), 1)
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

**Edit:**

Formula to find `Name` with minimum `Score`:

```
=INDEX(Table1,MATCH(AGGREGATE(15,6,Table1[Score]/(Table1[Subject]=F5),1),(Table1[Score])*(Table1[Subject]=F5),0),1)
```

Comment: Thanks. Excellent use of arrays. However, I wonder why the use of semi-colon in the formula. When I tried using it I got an error that there's a problem with the formula. Is it a setting  s issue in Excel?

Comment: No, it is Regional settings for my system. Just forgot replace when posting answer. Edited.

Comment: There's a little problem. This method does not work with minimum as the `min()` function always return zero. How do I adopt the formula for this purpose?

Comment: You can add an ```AGGREGATE``` function to the formula. See edit